# Sounds Italian?

Tags: knowledge, visual

[image]

It starts Italian but it is not. What is the missing color?

**Improving puzzle thanks to @will's answer**
Why is Orange the missing color?

Comment: If the edit didn't specify that the missing colour is orange, I would have guessed it to be purple ('plum', one might say...) because of the 6 playable characters in [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluedo)...

Comment: Plug for my meta post: [Re-asking a question when an unintended answer is given](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6983/69582)

Comment: Are the specific hues important, or the puzzle is still solvable as "green, white, red, yellow, blue, [orange]"?

Comment: Is the white rectangle one of the missing colors or is that where the Orange should go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are

> racing flags, so we’re missing black.  Note that the question asks for the missing color not the missing flag, so the checkered flag is covered by black and white.  The “move over” flag (blue with yellow stripe) is also covered by blue and yellow. [image] (Image from here:  https://www.parkerflags.com/product/auto-racing-flag-set-without-poles/)

> “Starts Italian” is referring to the first three colors matching the italian flag but also to the history of Italy in racing.

Alternative partial answer (but not as clean):

> they’re countries. Italy is green-white-red. Romanian flag is red—yellow-blue.  Ukrainian flag is yellow-blue.  Columbia is yellow-blue-red, so the next one in the sequence could be another red.  I think there are multiple possible flags that fit the sequence though. And I know a couple of those color sets are backwards but suppose the wind is blowing right to left.

I thought of another one!  This is also not as clean as the first one, but it satisfies the new requirement for orange to be one of the colors.  These are:

> standard colors for marking existing utilities prior to excavation.  Green = Sewer, White = Excavation Limits, Red = Electric, Yellow = Gas, Blue = Water, Orange = Communications.  This excludes survey (pink) because that's not part of the utility marking, and it excludes irrigation (purple) because the utility companies don't mark private lines.[image]

Comment: I did not think of that when creating my puzzle! +1

Comment: @JHKA if there are multiple 'correct' answers the question may need to be more focused

Answer (score 1):

Three primary colors, a secondary color, and a missing color.

If the Green is any indication to the missing color, then the missing color is either orange OR purple.

While the original post edits the answer to be Orange, my argument for Purple is:

We have three primary and secondary colors. In Primary, there is Cool and Warm colors. While Blue is the Cool color, and Yellow is a Warm color, Red can technically fall between the two, but generally leans Warm. If you mix colors to get Orange, you are getting a more Warmer color than you would if you mixed Violet/Purple.

The Green mix is equal parts Warm and Cool.
The Orange would be one parts Warm to one parts Warm/Cool, giving you a slightly warmer color.
If you mixed Violet; which would be one parts Cool to one parts Warm, the color band would be a little more balanced. Neutral, Neutral, Warm, Warm, Cool.

Why the color could be Orange: (I will now bite my nose off to spite my face)

Every color vibrates at a certain frequency.

Orange at around ~610nm.
Violet at near ~380nm.

(nm = nanometer, one billionth of a meter(if you can fathom such a measurement)

Using Red as our visual fulcrum, at ~740nm, the Yellow(~585nm), and Blue (~445nm) are emanating ~1030nm.

The Green (~520nm) is a nice mid-range wavelength to start with on the left side of our Red.

If we make our missing color Orange (~610nm) our left side sits at ~1130nm (~100nm higher)

versus

Violet as our missing color(~380) making the left side ~900nm, (~130nm lower)

The numbers used to represent each colors' wavelength were obviously pushed so that the numbers made sense in the end (a balanced ledger of light, versus an unbalanced one) but the numbers used ARE within the limits of each color's possible wavelength output. (shades of blue can range from as low as 420nm to as high as 460nm before becoming a different color that we can perceive with our current eye. So my choice of 445nm works.) (visually speaking, also, the color portrayed on screen is near that wavelength as well)

I guess Mathematically speaking, it IS orange, as it balances the sides a bit more evenly.

But in the theory of color, I still consider the answer to be purple/violet.

Comment: Nice answer, heh!